# Use Xpath To Retrieve Elements

Tags: xpath

HTML Portion:

```
<div class="abc">
    <div style="text-align:left; itemscopr itemtype="xyz">
        <h1 itemtype="mno"> I want this text </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using

```
$text = $xpath->query('//div[class="abc"]/div/h1]
```

but I am getting no value. Please help me as I am new to it.

Comment: maybe you missed the text()[1] at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try

```
//div[@class="abc"]/div/h1
```

The difference is in the `@` sign before `class`, because [the `attribute` axis is accessed this way](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev). When you omit the `@` sign, it looks for node names (tag names).

This returns you the whole `h1` node (or, rather, a node-set containing all the matching `h1` nodes).

If you only wanted the text from the element, try the [`evaluate`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.evaluate.php) function instead:

```
$text = $xpath->evaluate("//div[@class='abc']/div/h1/text()")
```

Comment: I have tried this but i am not getting an empty result. How do I retrieve value from this. I have also tried it using text() at the end but no luck. Is there any other way maybe using regex to retrieve or using xpath is better option ?

Comment: @user2140852 I edit my answer to take in into account. Better now?

Comment: Also, make sure that you're treating the result from `query` as a node-set. Therefore, you should loop over all the elements - see examples [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php).

Comment: Still not working . If I try to echo $text it is giving me following error -

Comment: Object of class DOMNodeList could not be converted to string

Comment: @user2140852 Exactly what I said in the last comment. It's a whole collection of elements (possibly holding one result), not a single element. Loop over it or just select the first one.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs Slanec . I am still to figure out whats going wrong. It is giving me empty set. I am on this for past few hours and even I am not sure whats wrong. I'll read and look into it again.